# Why is the code just after wait method not invoked

Tags: java, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I have a customer account class with below 2 methods, addBalance and deductBalance.

```
class CustomerAccount
{
    
    private int balance;
    int getBalance() { return balance;}
    CustomerAccount() {balance=0;}
    boolean deductBalance(final int amount)
    {
        System.out.println("> invoked to deduct :" + amount);
        synchronized (this)
        {
            while (balance <= amount)
            {
                try {wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {TestWaitNotifyBasic.logException(e);}
                System.out.println("> hey I was notified for cutting amount:" + amount);
            }
            balance-= amount;
        }
        System.out.println("> deducted:" + amount);
        return true;
    }
    boolean addBalance(final int amount)
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            balance += amount;
            notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("> balance added: " + amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Below is the consuming class with main method. The idea is to have threads wait for synchronized block until notifyAll is called.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;



public class TestWaitNotifyBasic
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final CustomerAccount chuck = new CustomerAccount();

        IntFunction<Runnable> addBalance = (amount) -> { return () -> chuck.addBalance(amount);};
        IntFunction<Runnable> deductBalance = (amount) -> { return () -> chuck.deductBalance(amount);};

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

        //balance deduction
        threadPool.execute(deductBalance.apply(1000) );
        threadPool.execute(deductBalance.apply(50) );
        threadPool.execute(deductBalance.apply(5000));

        //balance addition
        threadPool.execute(addBalance.apply(900));
        threadPool.execute(addBalance.apply(40));
        threadPool.execute(addBalance.apply(80));
        threadPool.execute(addBalance.apply(8000));

        threadPool.shutdown();
        while (!threadPool.isTerminated())
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e) {{logException(e);}}
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------" );
        System.out.println("thread operations finished, final balance : " + chuck.getBalance());
        int actualBalance = (900+40+80+8000)-(1000+50+5000);
        System.out.println("Validity check " + actualBalance);
    }

    static void logException(InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("###########interruptedexception#########" + e);
    }

}
```

Below is my console output

```
> balance added: 80
> invoked to deduct :1000
> balance added: 8000
> invoked to deduct :5000
> invoked to deduct :50
> balance added: 900
> balance added: 40
> deducted:5000
> deducted:50
> deducted:1000
----------------------
thread operations finished, final balance : 2970
Validity check 2970
```

The question I have is, why the below is not printed in console output

> System.out.println("> hey I was notified for cutting amount:" + amount);

This method is written next to wait() of deduct balance method in CustomerAccount class.

Comment: **NEVER** write `catch (InterruptedException e) {}`. atleast log exception

Comment: @Jens , this is for practice.. not a production code.

Comment: That is no reason for let the catch-Block blank. youwill never see if there is an exception which can change the program flow

Comment: The probable reason is that none of the deducting threads has gotten into the synchronized block before the "add 8000" did. Therefore, they never got into the `while` loop.

Comment: @Jens added the logging for exception.

Comment: @RealSkeptic indeed. Tried debug with breakpoint on first line of loop. Never executed.

Comment: In any case, if you are going to use this code, you *shouldn't* be deducting the money outside of the synchronized block. This would mean that other threads would not see the deduction.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, thanks. I have modified it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@RealSkeptic's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) comment,  modified the addBalance Thread to sleep before entering execution. Post this all the sysouts got executed

The behavior of code posted above was that the addBalance threads would get executed before the deductBalance thread entered the synchronized block.

With below method for addBalance, the ouptut changes.

```
boolean addBalance(final int amount)
    {
        try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {{TestWaitNotifyBasic.logException(e);}}
        synchronized (this)
        {
            balance += amount;
            notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("> balance added: " + amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Console output post method change:

```
> invoked to deduct :50
> invoked to deduct :1000
> invoked to deduct :5000
> balance added: 900
> balance added: 40
> hey I was notified for cutting amount:50
> balance added: 8000
> balance added: 80
> hey I was notified for cutting amount:5000
> deducted:50
> hey I was notified for cutting amount:1000
> deducted:1000
> deducted:5000

----------------------
thread operations finished, final balance : 2970
Validity check 2970
```

Comment: there is no problem in the original code, I just wanted to see the console output. The question was "why the console output is not seen"?

Comment: That's what I meant. I got your expected output when I ran your original code, i.e. `> hey I was notified for cutting amount` did appear in the console when I ran your original code.